# webpack: transpiling file so out put is next to the source file

Tags: javascript, typescript, webpack

I am using webpack to turn my ts in js. I want the js files to be placed at the same location as their ts sources. right now I am 'cheating' by having many entry points. the entry points are the path to the file.

here is the snippet of my config

```
entry: {
    'path/to/my/file':'path/to/my/file.ts',
    'other/path/to/other/file':'other/path/to/other/file.ts'
},

output: {
    path: rootFolder,
    publicPath: outputFolderName + '/',
    filename: '[name].js'
}
```

this currently works. I was wondering if there was a cleaner way to do this. Some way of not depending on having the name of the entry point be the path so that the entry points are more flexible.

Comment: Why don't you use a default typescript compiler feature? It allows you to do this without webpack

Answer (score 0):

You are using wrong tool for this job. Webpack is bundler, it is designed to bundle many files into single package.

What you want to do is to compile Typescript into Javascript. Use typescript compiler for that. Just use/run `tsc`.

Just make sure `outDir` in `tsconfig.json` is equal `.` or absent at all.

You might need to install it globally for ease of use

```
npm install -g typescript
```